# Can't Mount Windows 7 Share on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: windows-7, share, cifs, smb

Installed Ubuntu 11.10 64bit today and got to a problem.
Can't connect to Windows 7 shared folders.

I have tried every single method I could find on google. Mount with "mount cifs", "smbmount", changed homegroups, etc and no luck.

Windows 7 is clean setup with no-password sharing enabled. Other windows computers can access shares without a problem.

On ubuntu I can see windows 7 under WindowsNetworks->WORKGROUP> but nothing.

Edit: It looks like now I can see shares of other windows 7 computer (with login and password) but not the one I need (without login and password)

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think the "simple" Windows Homegroup Shares dont work, you have to share folders the 'old' way (right click on folder, properties, sharing or similar)

Comment: I tried every possible way of sharing from win7. Hell I can see win xp shares but not win7. Microsoft did something nasty there. Installing linux for storage :|

Comment: are you using any special characters in the user passwords? like #?

Comment: homegroup share will not work since remember you actually have to enter the password for homegroup joining, which is managed by win 7. and ubuntu has no idea about that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this problem after upgrading from Ubuntu 10.x.  installing smbfs with

```
sudo apt-get install smbfs
```

fixed it.  I was connecting to a network drive, though, not a window$ box.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could not find windows shares under Browse Network, but could under `/mnt/hgfs` (which you can navigate to in Nautilus).